# match the first char of occurring chars (they must be next to eachother)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string array filled with strings which looks something like this.

```
let strings = ["foo", "bar", ", dog", ",, and cats"];
```

What I have been trying to do was to convert the string array to a string and then replace the commas with spaces, but only the commas that occur first.

```
strings.toString() // "foo,bar,, dog,,, and cats"
strings.toString().replace(match/g, " ") // "foo bar , dog ,, and cats"
```

I'm not entirely sure how I would go on about using regex for this, I can't really word my question that well so I wasn't able to find related questions on so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `,(,*)` regex to match one comma and optional commas captured in group1 and replace it with a space and contents of group1 captures. That way, first comma will get replaced with a space and remaining commas will get retained as it is.

JS code demo,

```js
let strings = ["foo", "bar", ", dog", ",, and cats"];
console.log(strings.toString().replace(/,(,*)/g,' $1'));
```